# Im wondering why I get a getaddrinfo error on my rasberry pi

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, dns, getaddrinfo

Im working on a self watering plant system. Link here https://www.hackster.io/demirhanaydin/waterpi-houseplant-remote-watering-and-monitoring-system-340400. I followed all the steps and have modified the code slightly for my lcd to work. I keep running into this error and I'm not sure how to fix it. I have found similar issues online but none that quite explain how to fix this issue. Any help would be appreciated.

```
events.js:141
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^

Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND a2paxuwr910.iot.us-west-2.amazonaws.com a2paxuwr910oz.iot.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:883
at errnoException (dns.js:26:10)
at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:77:26)
```

Comment: You need to actually post the code which is throwing the error or we have very little chance of helping.  But ENOTFOUND basically means the host name you're specifying doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

getaddrinfo() is a system call that handles hostname resolution for you. Your system either can't speak to the internet in general, or its DNS resolver (named in /etc/hosts) in particular. Resolve that, and this code should work properly.

Separately, you want to make sure you handle errors like this in your code; DNS, networks, system calls-- all of these can fail.